# Retrive value from JSON using service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm a beginner in AngularJS. I'm here trying to fetch the data from JSON using service and display it. I'm having separate files for controllers, services. I'm unable to find out what I'm doing wrong here. I learned that we return an object in case of factory but, I'm not sure how to return the value when using services. The code that I tried is below.

HTML: I have an `index.html` file into which I load this HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="comp">
    {{capcino}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("retailapp");

app.controller("comp", function($scope, elecservice){
    $scope.capcino = elecservice.getval();
});
```

Service:

```
angular.module("retailapp").service("elecservice", serjson);

function serjson($http){
    var val = "";

    this.getval = function(){
        $http.get("/elec.json").success(function(res){
            val = res.namet;
            return val;
        });
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
var app = angular.module("retailapp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/computer", {
        templateUrl : "computer.html",
        controller : "comp"
});
```

JSON:

```
{"namet" : "naysan"}
```

I want to display the value "capcino" in expression in HTML. I'm getting `undefined` for that value. Kindly help with explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write as follow:

```
var app = angular.module("retailapp");

    app.controller("comp", function($scope, elecservice){

        elecservice.getval().then(function(data){
        $scope.capcino = data;
    });    

    });
```

Comment: thanks for your input....I just tried as per your suggest, but Im getting error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

It's a promise so it sets $scope.capcino after it returns. Until that return occurs $scope.capcino is undefined.

```
var app = angular.module("retailapp");
    app.controller("comp", function($scope, elecservice){
        elecservice.getval().then(function(data){
        $scope.capcino = data;
    });    
});
```

Comment: You just copy from @Vaqif_RV answer.

Comment: @ElvinMammadov are you kidding? i have posted the explanation, code will be anyway the same!

Comment: You can write your explanation  as comment.

Comment: @ElvinMammadov I din't see that he has posted the answer before me, i was in the middle. i would have definitely done that :)

Comment: thanks for your input....I just tried as per your suggest, but Im getting error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Just change your controller to store the data.

```
$scope.yourFunc = function(params){
  YouService.function(params).then(function(result){
      $scope.yourVar = result.data;
    }
  })
```

}
  }